# Is it possible to get an estimate of the average CGPA or conventional system of marks for an engineering course in any Indian university?

Tags: university, engineering, india

How can a student of engineering compare themselves to other students of the same studies in their own university and elsewhere in the country?

Answer (score 2):

I just googled around a bit and it appears that Indian Universities print their grading scheme behind the student's transcript.

Here is an image: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-b0c360832d9a2bb3d45cf20f92295a78.webp

So that part is taken care of. If you find a transcript floating around online, you immediately get the grading scheme or the "conventional system of marks" as you put it for that particular univeristy.

I'm quite sure the "average CGPA" of a particular class in any University is not freely available information. You might need to reach out to the adminstrative staff for information regarding this and you will most likely be ignored unless you're a student of the university you're reaching out to.